# moodle Plugin type for dynamic multi-row user CV

Tags: plugins, moodle

I'm going to create a plugin for moodle that shows a CV like page for each user in frontend.
The data only are inserted by admins and users just can view the CV page.

I looked into moodle's plugin types but none of them except `local plugin` seems to be sufficient but it doesn't have admin section capabilities.

**My question is**: what **type** of moodle plugin should I use to be able to store custom structured rows of data for users in admin section and display them for each user in frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Moodle, the answer depends on where you want to display the output.

If you want an activity (in a course, or in the front page course) to hold the output, then an '[activity module](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Activity_modules)' is the right answer.

If you want to display the content (or a link to the main content) in a sidebar block, or in the central region on the My home / Dashboard page, then a '[block](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks)' is the right answer.

If your plugin is a form of report, that should be added to the list of available reports at the course or system level, then a '[report](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Reports)' plugin would be best.

If you just want a link in the admin settings menu (or, for that matter, to insert a link in the navigation block or in the course or activity settings block), then a '[local](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins)' plugin is the right answer (in retrospect the name 'local' is no longer a good fit for these plugin types, but it's too late to change it now).

Comment: Hi, My plugin doesn't depend on course but stores information for user (like a profile field but with the difference that it is filled from admin area and is not a single or limited number of fields but it is unlimited numbers of rows that will be shown to user as a table); so I have input mechanism in admin area and view in user area